# Question on the outer product used to construct this 2-Qbit state

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-information, outer-product

I am reading a book on quantum computing. The author is constructing an arbitrary 2-Qbit state from unitary transformations. I need help understanding on step in his logic. For those unfamiliar with with quantum computing,

$$
\begin{align}
    |0\rangle &= \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}, \quad
    |1\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           1
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

And

$$
\begin{align}
    |00\rangle &= \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           0 \\
           0 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}, \quad
    |01\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           1 \\
           0 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}, \quad
    |10\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           0 \\
           1 \\
           0
         \end{bmatrix}, \quad
    |11\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           0 \\
           0 \\
           1
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

He starts by noting that the general 2-Qbit state has the form

$$
|\Psi\rangle = a_{00}|00\rangle + a_{01}|01\rangle + a_{10}|10\rangle + a_{11}|11\rangle
$$

This can also be written as:

$$
|\Psi\rangle = |0\rangle \otimes |\psi\rangle + |1\rangle \otimes |\phi\rangle
$$
$$
|\psi\rangle = a_{00}|0\rangle + a_{01}|1\rangle
$$
$$
|\phi\rangle = a_{10}|0\rangle + a_{11}|1\rangle
$$

So far so good. Next the author says apply $ \textbf{u} \otimes \textbf{1}  $ to $ |\Psi\rangle $, where $ \textbf{u} $ is a linear transformation, whose action on the computational basis is of the form:

$$
\textbf{u}|0\rangle = a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle, \quad \textbf{u}|1\rangle = -b^*|0\rangle + a^*|1\rangle; \quad |a|^2 + |b|^2 = 1
$$

The author doesn't state this, but I assume $ a,b \in \mathbb{C} $ and $ a^* $ and $ b^* $ are the complex conjugates of $ a $ and $ b $ respectively. Also unstated but assumed by me is that $ \textbf{u} $ is a $ 2x2 $ matrix and $ \textbf{1} $ is the $ 2x2 $ identity.

Now comes the part I don't understand. The author states:

$$
(\textbf{u} \otimes \textbf{1})|\Psi\rangle = (a|0\rangle + b|1\rangle) \otimes |\psi\rangle + (-b^*|0\rangle + a^*|1\rangle) \otimes |\phi\rangle
$$

In order for the above to be true, it would seem that

$$
(\textbf{u} \otimes \textbf{1})|\Psi\rangle = \textbf{u} |0\rangle \otimes |\psi\rangle + \textbf{u}|1\rangle \otimes |\phi\rangle
$$

But I don't understand why.

Comment: Long story short: $(A \otimes B)(C \otimes D) =  (AC)\otimes (BD)$.  As for the "why": of course we could verify that the formula works for matrices in general, but I would rather say that the fact that $(A \otimes B)(v \otimes w) = (Av) \otimes (Bw)$ works for vectors $v$ and $w$ is the *definition* of the [tensor product of linear maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_linear_maps).

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense